# New line carriage return while writing to file in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have a program which accept a parameter the file name.
I have one more file where I am storing all the list of files names that are being passed.
Now when ever a file name is passed, I want to add it to the list of file names along with a carriage return.

Example:

```
Names.txt
_______________
Sample1.txt
Sample2.txt
Sample3.txt
```

and so on..

I have tried it but unable to get the values into new line.
Can you please help.

```
    echo on


@REM parameter  1 = path and file to copy


SET saveloc=E:\Temp\201405\receivedfiles.txt

SET "FileList="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (%saveloc%) Do (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    Call SET FileList=%%FileList%%%%A&echo.
)
Set FileList=%FileList%%1%

echo %FileList%>%saveloc%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    :: arg1 = name of file. If not present, leave the batch file
    if "%~1"=="" exit /b 1

    :: Where to save the information
    set "saveloc=E:\Temp\201405\receivedfiles.txt"

    :: Append the argument to the log
    >> "%saveloc%" echo(%~1
```

When redirecting output to a file `>` will overwrite the target file. Use `>>` to append to file.

Comment: It is not writing anything to the file, if I do like this.

Comment: @user788312, are you passing the file as first argument to the batch file? If you pass the file and you have rights to write to the log file it should write the information to it. How are you calling the batch file?

Comment: testnewline.cmd C:\Temp\sample.txt

Comment: @user788312, for me, it is working. Please, remove the `@echo off` and see what is executed when you call the batch.